# Cocos2d - Problems with .pvr.ccz spritesheet (incorrect position, blurry) created with TexturePacker

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, textures, texturepacker

I have a problem by using the .pvr.ccz format. I have a simple spritesheet with a few sprites on it created by TexturePacker. It's loaded like in my example code below.

```
@implementation MainScene

- (id)init
{
    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"spritesheet.plist"];
    CCSprite * sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"play-button.png"]];
    sprite.position = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
    sprite.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    [self addChild:sprite];

    // done
    return self;
}
@end
```

The spritesheet is loaded and I don't get any warnings or errors in the console. But somehow the sprite (play-button.png) is first of all blurry and on the second hand it's the wrong position on the spritesheet (so it's a half of another sprite and not the playbutton).

In TexturePacker I have the following options selected:

[image: Texturepacker]

I read many articles about the advantages of using pvr.ccz. I use the cocos2d version 3.5. So did I miss something in my code or is there an option in Texturepacker?

Comment: This was the solution. Can you add your comment as an answer in order to accept your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a point in time (memory fails) cocos2d and TP changed the .pvr format (produced and read) to the normal 'flipped' version. Thus, just select the `Flip PVR` check-box in TP, and the rendering should be fine.